# R - Count unique/distinct values in two columns together per group

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, count, distinct

### R - Count unique/distinct values in two columns together

Hi everyone. I have a panel of electoral behaviour but I am having problems to compute a new variable that would capture unique values (parties) of my two columns `Party` and `Party2013` per group. The column `Party2013` measures the vote in election 2013 and `Party` measures voters intentions after 2013. Everytime I try `n_distinct` or `length` I get the count of unique values in both columns separately but not as a sum.

```
ID  Wave  Party Party2013
1    1      A      A
1    2      A      NA
1    3      B      NA
1    4      B      NA
```

Based on the example above I normally get the count of **3** instead of desired **2**.
I´ve tried following commands but got only the number of separate unique values:

```
data %>% group_by(ID) %>% distinct(Party, Party2013, .keep_all = TRUE) %> dplyr::summarise(Party_Party2013 = n())
```

or

```
ddply(data, .(ID), mutate, count = length(unique(Party, Party2013)))
```

The expected outcome would as follows:

```
ID  Wave  Party Party2013  Count
1    1      A      A         2
1    2      A      NA        2
1    3      B      NA        2
1    4      B      NA        2
2    1      A      C         3
2    2      B      NA        3
2    3      B      NA        3
2    4      B      NA        3
```

I would very much appreciate any advice on how to count the overall number of unique parties across the two columns per group and not the number of distinct values per each one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subset the data from `cur_data()` and `unlist` the data to get a vector. Use `n_distinct` to count number of unique values.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Count = n_distinct(unlist(select(cur_data(), 
                   Party, Party2013)), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup


#     ID  Wave Party Party2013 Count
#  <int> <int> <chr> <chr>     <int>
#1     1     1 A     A             2
#2     1     2 A     NA            2
#3     1     3 B     NA            2
#4     1     4 B     NA            2
#5     2     1 A     C             3
#6     2     2 B     NA            3
#7     2     3 B     NA            3
#8     2     4 B     NA            3
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Wave = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), Party = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "A", 
"B", "B", "B"), Party2013 = c("A", NA, NA, NA, "C", NA, NA, NA
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Answer (score 0):

In situations like this I always like to simplify the problem and change the data into the long format since it is easier to solve problems like this if all of your values are in one column. With `pivot_longer()` you can also use the argument `values_drop_na = TRUE` to drop `NAs` which were counted in your example:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

data <- read.table(text = 
"ID  Wave  Party Party2013
1    1      A      A 
1    2      A      NA
1    3      B      NA
1    4      B      NA
2    1      A      C 
2    2      B      NA
2    3      B      NA
2    4      B      NA", header = TRUE)

data %>% pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Party"), values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(Count = n_distinct(value)) %>% merge(data, .)
#>   ID Wave Party Party2013 Count
#> 1  1    1     A         A     2
#> 2  1    2     A      <NA>     2
#> 3  1    3     B      <NA>     2
#> 4  1    4     B      <NA>     2
#> 5  2    1     A         C     3
#> 6  2    2     B      <NA>     3
#> 7  2    3     B      <NA>     3
#> 8  2    4     B      <NA>     3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can also and this way:

```
library(dplyr)

data <- read.table(text = 
                     "ID  Wave  Party Party2013
1    1      A      A 
1    2      A      NA
1    3      B      NA
1    4      B      NA
2    1      A      C 
2    2      B      NA
2    3      B      NA
2    4      B      NA", header = TRUE)


data %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%  
  mutate(Count = paste(Party, Party2013) %>% 
           unique %>% length() %>% 
           rep(length(Party)))
```

output

```
# A tibble: 8 x 5
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID  Wave Party Party2013 Count
  <int> <int> <chr> <chr>     <int>
1     1     1 A     A             3
2     1     2 A     NA            3
3     1     3 B     NA            3
4     1     4 B     NA            3
5     2     1 A     C             2
6     2     2 B     NA            2
7     2     3 B     NA            2
8     2     4 B     NA            2
```